# Zero or not zero? Product of two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

I'd like to know if the product of the following two vectors is zero or not without directly multiplying them or by avoiding raising $b^n$. Here, $b=110$ but in general can be a positive integer greater than 1.

Is there a shortcut?

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 b^0 & b^1 & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & b^5 & b^6 &
   b^7 & b^8 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 275220 \\
 -31542 \\
 1006104 \\
 796716 \\
 2266374 \\
 1131690 \\
 937284 \\
 -3336 \\
 -48 \\
\end{array}
\right)
= 0 \rm{\,? \;\;Yes!}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 b^0 & b^1 & b^2 & b^3 & b^4 & b^5 & b^6 &
   b^7 & b^8 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 275220 \\
 -31542 \\
 1006104 \\
 796716 \\
 2266374 \\
 1131690 \\
 937284 \\
 -3336 \\
 -48 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\\
 275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5+
 937284 b^6 -3336 b^7 -48 b^8
$$
Now, using $b^n=110b^{n-1}$ and working down from the largest power, you get
$$275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5+
 937284 b^6 -3336 b^7 -48 b^8 =\\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5+
 937284 b^6 -3336 b^7 -5280 b^7= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5+
 937284 b^6 -8616 b^7= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5+
 937284 b^6 -947760 b^6= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5+
-10476 b^6= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
 1131690 b^5
-1152360 b^5= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
-20670 b^5= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
-2273700 b^4= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
 2266374 b^4+
-2273700 b^4= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
-7326 b^4= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2+ 796716 b^3+
-805860 b^3= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2-9144 b^3= \\
275220 -31542b+ 1006104b^2-1005840 b^2= \\
275220 -31542b+264 b^2= \\
275220 -31542b+29040 b= \\
275220 -2502 b= \\
275220 -275220=0 $$

Note that at every point you only add subtract and multiply not too large numbers by 110, and the numbers don't become too large.

Comment: Great answer, but I think writing the computations in a matrix form is far more readable.

Comment: This actually answers my second question: How to construct such vectors? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After performing the dot product, this question reduces to asking about finding the roots of the resulting polynomial.

(It happens that $b=110$ is the only integer solution to this system, as a computational package will verify, but I will answer this question more generally in case you were looking to do this with other potential column vectors.)

I'm not aware of any particularly fast algorithm to find roots by hand without getting our hands a little bit messy computationally. There are, however, a few conditions that you could check that might indicate if no solution is possible, or to quickly rule out if a particular value of $b$ cannot be a solution.

I'm going to name the elements in your column vector $a_0,\dots, a_8$ in keeping with convention for dealing with polynomials. That is, $a_0 = 275220$ and $a_8=-48$.

The **[Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)** gives us some conditions that the roots have to conform to.

The rational root theorem tells us that any value of $b$ that gives a rational-valued solution to this problem will be in the form $b=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ is an integer factor of $a_0$ and $q$ is an integer factor of $a_8$, for all such $p$ and $q$ that are relatively prime.

Now, since we're only after integer solutions, and we know that for any choice of $q\neq 1$ we will end up with a fraction, we can drastically simplify our search and say that all integer solutions will be of the form $b=p$ where $p$ is an integer factor of $a_0$.

So, if the particular value of $b$ you're considering does not divide $275220$, it definitely *cannot* be a solution. On the other hand, if it does divide, we cannot say anything conclusively.

This might reduce your search a great deal, but unfortunately this cannot tell you conclusively if a particular value of $b$ is a root.

If you were also considering many different possible column vectors rather than the particular one you have there, then something like Eisenstein's criterion might come in handy for rejecting a solution to this system in general, but that is not so relevant if this particular column vector is the only one you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do know what b is, I'm looking for the coeffs that would make it a zero.